# filtering keyboard input with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

I recently broke my keyboard, and wrote some very makeshift, inefficient programs in autohotkey to fix them

here are the outputs of my current laptop keyboard:
    y = ry
    h = fh
    n = {enter}+n
    6 = 46

I currently have 4 autohotkey files running for each broken key. Below is the file for h

hadjust.ahk

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

while true {

KeyWait, h,D
Sleep 20
Send {BS}
Send {BS}
Send {h}


}
```

how can I combine the four .ahk files into 1? And is there a better way to do this?

** edit I found a way to do it in one file, but I cant get the n/enter key to work.

Here is the code...

stackadjust.ahk

```
:?*:fh::h
:?*:hf::h
:?*:ry::y
:?*:yr::y
:?*:46::6
:?*:64::6
:?*:n{Enter}::n
:?*:{Enter}n::n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your last two entries you could use the following code:

```
:*:n`n::n
:*:`nn::n

;Comment: `n = {Enter}
```

Comment: Thanks Robert, it now works for a repeated n, but it still does not work in a sentence.

Comment: I just tried changing it to 

    :?*:n`n::n
    :?*:`nn::n

and its working a lot better, but the newline character slips through here and there.

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard sends the double key at roughly the same time,
it's possible to make them a double hotkey.

This way you could still type words like "fury"...

```
y & r::send, {blind}r
$y::send, {blind}y
$+y::send, {blind}Y
4 & 6::send, {blind}6
$4::send, {blind}4
$+4::send, {blind}$
f & h::send, {blind}h
$f::send, {blind}f
$+f::send, {blind}F
n & Enter::send, {blind}n
$n::send, {blind}n
$+n::send, {blind}N
$Enter::
if (A_PriorHotkey = "n") and (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 500)
{
  Soundbeep, 500, 200
  return
}
Send, {Enter}
return
```

Sending "blind" (against the shift, alt and ctrl status)
is probably not necessary, but doesn't hurt.
Update: As Enter seems to be more stuck, I will remove Enter up to
500ms after the last n. In this case I'm beeping to give a notetice.

Comment: thanks 576i. that seems to be working well, and for all words. I still am getting the enter key slipping through though in places such as fb chat, chrome address bar, and anything else where the enter key has an action

Comment: edited the script to catch any enter key pressed up to 500 ms after a "n". Also I added the "shifted" keys because the script was blockig capital letters. I Alt+Cltr combinations are killed by this script, you need to add them, too.

Dont forget to mark this as solved if it works otherwise :)

Comment: Sorry, still not working:/ Usually, when I push 'n' it outputs 'enter' and then'n', but sometimes switches order. I need the something like `
$Enter::
elapsedTime = 0
while(elapsed time < 500){
if(n is pressed){
send n
return}
Sleep 50
elapsedTime += 50
}
return
}`
but cant find a good way to check if n is pressed

Comment: OK, you are looking for the "GetKeyState" command. So you'd need to extend the Enter Hotkey to loop for 500 ms and get the state of the n-key and if it's pressed, quit. The n will then fire it's own hotkey. Alas I don't have time to write the full script for you before the weekend...